# How to use a Puppet File Resource to give different permissions on a directory than to it's files?

Tags: ruby, linux, puppet

I would like to use Puppet to manage a directory. I want the directory to be owned by user root and group admin, with 0770 permissions.

I would like all files in the directory to be owned by user apache and group admin with 0600 permissions.

I have yet to find a way to achieve this using the file resource in Puppet. I have tried using two resources like so:

```
file { 'phpsessions_files':
    path => '/var/phpsessions',
    ensure => directory,
    owner => 'apache',
    group => 'admin',
    mode => 0600,
    recurse => true,
    before => File['phpsessions_dir'],
}

file { 'phpsessions_dir':
    path => '/var/phpsessions',
    recurse => false,
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'admin',
    mode => 0770,
}
```

But I am not allowed to create two file resources to the same path and I can't see how to achieve what I want with just one resource.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a define containing an exec to change the mode of the directory after it is recursed.

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/File_Permission_Check_Patterns

Comment: How this will change the ownership of the file or directory which is already set by puppet file type ? If you try to change it via exec, the rules will be non-convergent.

Comment: Good point. My fault, didn't notice the ownership change. Maybe add another exec to the define ensure that ownership is set correctly.

Comment: That won't do either. You have to add a function that will loop over all the files and subdirectories inside the parent one to change the permissions and ownerships.

Comment: sadly Puppetlabs shut the wiki down. link still in the archive.org though http://web.archive.org/web/20160401113847/http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/File_Permission_Check_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible in puppet.  i would manage **only** the following

```
  file { 'phpsessions_dir':
      path => '/var/phpsessions',
      recurse => false,
      owner => 'root',
      group => 'admin',
      mode => 0770,
  }
```

php/apache should create the files within this folder with the correct permissions, If they don't fix that in [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path).  If you are worried that something else is gonna come along and change the permissions then fall back to a cron job or better yet a systemd.timer to periodicity check and correct them